# Avoiding copies in exception handling

Tags: c++, exception

Can I avoid the copying of object in the following way?

```
MyClass Obj;

try {
    throw &Obj;
}
catch(MyClass *a) {

}
```

Comment: Object copying is nothing compared to overhead associated with throwing an exception, and catching it. And amount of generated code to do so... So don't worry about it. If you feel like throwing non-copyable, or extremely expensive to copy object - you should not use it as an exception object at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the object is too expensive to copy, it should not be thrown as an exception - full stop. Exception classes should be fairly simple and light-weight. And you should always catch exceptions by reference (probably by const reference) - catching pointers is bad style. So your code should better be written:

```
try {
    throw MyClass();
}
catch( const MyClass & a) {
}
```

In response to your comment, this:

```
struct A {
    A() {}
    private:
    A( const A & ) {}
};

int main() {
    throw A();
}
```

should be an error. But you simply should not be prohibiting copying of classes you want to throw as exceptions - why are you doing this?

Comment: Isn't it possible that you'd want to throw some context about the exception, such as what caused it or data required to back out of a transaction for example? That might cause the exception object to be not so light-weight.

Comment: @Mark Some context, sure - my exception class contains a message, file name and line number. Data needed to back out  a transaction - no. The transaction backout may be done in response to an exception, but the backout data should be stored elsewhere, like in a transaction log. Apart from anything else, you might want to backout a transaction in non-exceptional circumstances.

Comment: In this example, Would the compiler use its own special copy-constructor? I have it in private section but I can still compile it.

Comment: Hmm ok, It didn't work. But It compiles on VC++8.0 that I have. http://ideone.com/k7zRV

Comment: @user Post code here. And you still haven't said why you think you need to do this.

Comment: I'm only doing this because I don't want the whole thing to be copied.

Comment: But first i think i should change my compiler that is allowing a copy.

Comment: @user Gah! But why don't you want it to be copied???????? And no, you should not change your compiler (at least WRT this issue), you should change your design.

Comment: Ok, but because in design if i can avoid a copy, why would i create a copy of object that is already allocated?

Comment: @user Good C++ code is all about making copies where appropriate, not about avoiding making them. and it is completely appropriate to copy exception objects. But maybe you are misusing exceptions - they are not intended as a general mechanism for moving objects of any old type around. But you have to be more forthcoming, both by posting real code here and describing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Right, I think i understand your point, Because it may not be always possible to avoid a copy but it still should be done by using a copy.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it.

Consider this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#define X() (std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "\n")

struct MyClass {
 MyClass() { X(); }
 ~MyClass() { X(); }
};

void f() {
 MyClass Obj;
 throw &Obj;
}

int main() {
 try {
  f();
 } catch(MyClass *a) {
  X();
 }
}
```

the output of which is this:

```
MyClass
~MyClass
main
```

Notice that the pointed-to object is destroyed before the program entered the catch block. This means that we must not dereference `a` in the catch block, severely limiting its usefulness.

Comment: In this case, using `throw new MyClass()` could make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to avoid copying an exception object is to throw a *pointer* to the object, as you have done in your example. You must make sure that the object is static or heap allocated, not a local object that will disappear after leaving the code block during the throw.

**Edit:** Another approach comes to mind. You can create your own exception class (which should be derived from `std::exception` or one of its children) with the pointer as a member, then throw that. If you use a smart pointer such as `shared_ptr` you won't have to worry about the lifetime of the contained object.

Comment: However if Obj is declared in the same function as the throw then what happens is undefined or worse as the Obj is out of scope when you catch it

Comment: @Neil, I wouldn't say it's a great idea - but Microsoft's MFC gets away with it.

Comment: There's also the issue of resource management in the sense of "who cleans up the exception object that's floating around on the heap".

Comment: @Mark: MFC has nothing to be proud of, unfortunately. It's a shame, not a library.

Comment: More Effective C++ has a good overview of why throwing and catching pointers is A Bad Idea - it's Item 13 in the first ed.

Comment: @Mark This isn't really a lifetime issue. Please don't encourage newbies into flights of fantasy about throwing shared pointers. The correct way to use exceptions in C++ is to throw a value and catch a const reference. And yes, I do know that pointers are values, before the nitpickers start.

Comment: @Neil, I think you misunderstood my edit. I've changed it to be more clear. Since the OP hasn't come back to explain why they don't want to copy the object, I'm assuming they had a good reason until I get evidence to the contrary.

Answer (score 0):

It is syntactically correct and avoids the copy since the reference is being passed. But, usually an standard nameless exception object is constructed and is caught by the `catch` statement.